# How to normally distribute N topics among M writers such that each topic has exactly P writers?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to distribute this such that there is a normal(-ish) distribution of topics amongst writers. Is it possible to do so?

(Writer being an analogy for event publishers in computers)

Comment: Unclear whether a topic can be assigned to more than one writer. Unclear what you mean by 'normal-ish'. Maybe you can give a clarifying example for a particular choice of N, M, and P. Otherwise, I guess this question is going to be down-voted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Topics = 1,2,3,4,.......n ( consider these numbers as names of given topic )
Let choose p writers for the first topic (I.e 1)   mCp for one topic simillary for other topics mCp
Even for Nth. Topic it will be mCp
So for N topics 
= mCp* mCp* mCp* mCp..........*mCp

= {mCp}^n